# Routing issues with Angular 5 and Laravel 5 when the page is refresh

Tags: angular, laravel, npm, angular-cli, nodes

I developed an application with `Laravel 5.5` as back end and `Angular 5` as front end. I succeeded in building the Angular application into public/app of my Laravel application. I could now view the angular application from my browser using `http://localhost:8000/app`, and it functioned as expected. I now wrote this route to load the angular application on requesting `http://localhost:8000`

Here is the route code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('http://localhost:8000/app');
});
```

So the angular application is what you now see on requesting this link http://localhost:8000, and it works.
But when the angular application takes over, and i click on the about route of the angular it, it open the about page, but as soon as i refresh this same link i.e `http://localhost:8000/app/about` i get this error

> "SORRY THE PAGE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR CANNOT BE FOUND"

I could understand that the `laravel` part of the application takes over again and try find a route that opens this link `http://localhost:8000/app/about`, this is not present in the `laravel application` but the `angular application`, so i am having routing issues with my app.

I did some research an i had to hard coded this url on the browser `http://localhost:8000/app/#/about` and i could refresh the page with getting the about mentioned error.

I try adding this # symbol to my angular routes, but on the browser, the url becomes `http://localhost:8000/app/%23/about`, the `#` tends to appear as `%23` and is does not work when i refresh the page, i get the above mentioned error again.

Please can anyone help fix this issue, i will be very grateful, here is how my angular route is describe

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: '#/about',
        component: AboutComponent
    }
];
```

And this is how is called it on the html page

```
<li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="#/about">About</a></li>
```

Comment: Did you try the production build..ng build --prod --aot ?